# maximum principle in a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Generalize Proposition 2.3.2 to compact sets in a topological space.

Proposition 2.3.2 (Maximum principle). Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ is bounded. Furthermore, $f$ attains its maximum at some point $x_{max} \in X$, and also attains its minimum at some point $x_{min} \in X$.

I know that if $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is also compact. In a metric space, a compact set is bounded. Is this true in a topological space?

I have already proven this proposition in a metric space, using that every sequence in a compact set, there exists a convergent subsequence in $X$, and I don't think that I am allowed to use this in a topological space. How can I prove this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In a topological space there is no such thing as bounded set. You also cannot characterize compactness using sequences.

If $X$ is compact and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous then $f(X)$ is compact. This can be proved using definition of compactness using open covers. Hence, if $X$ is compact then, in the case $Y=\mathbb R$, the set of real numbers $f(X)$ is compact and any compact set in $\mathbb R$ is bounded This proves that $f(X)$ is bounded. Also $f(X)$ has a maximum and  a minimum  which give you the maximum and  a minimum of $f$.

Comment: What about if $X$ has the order topology? Is the statement OP is trying to phrase might be true in that case?

Answer (score 0):

1) Any continuous map between topological spaces maps compact sets to compact sets.

2) Every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded.

If you are not aware of these standard results, try proving them (exercise). Then it will be clear that the proposition holds for X being a topological space.

Suggestion : For understanding fundamentals of topological spaces, try reading book by Munkres on Topology.

Answer (score 0):

By the theorem in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593811/4280) we *can* say as a generalisation: let $X$ be compact and let $Y$ be a LOTS. (like $\Bbb R$ is. Then any continuous function $f: X \to Y$ assumes as minimum and a maximum.