# Compact ordered topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, order-theory, solution-verification

As a question inspired by [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592787/maximum-principle-in-a-topological-space/3592792#comment7386738_3592792). I was just wondering whether a compact ordered topological space, a space with the total order topology, has to have a maximum and a minimum?

I was thinking that if we consider a collection consisiting of open rays of the form $\mathcal{C}=\{ x\in X:x<y \}$.
Assume $X$ is unbounded from above, then $\mathcal{C}$ would be a cover since we have a total order. 
By compactness of $X$ and since the rays are open, there exists a finite subcover of the form:
$$ \mathcal{C}'=\Big\{ \{x\in X:x<y_k\}  \Big\}_{k=1}^n $$

Because $<$ is a total order, we can assume WLOG that $y_1<y_2<...<y_n$, and in particular:

$$ \cup_{k=1}^n \{x\in X:x<y_k\} =\{x\in X:x<y_n\}  $$
And therefore $\{x\in X:x<y_n\}=X $. But $y_n\not<y_n$, so this is a contradiction. So we have a maximal element.

In a similar argument with rays in the other direction, we have a minimal element.

Do these steps seem valid, and can we then use this to generalize the maximum principle in the aforementioned post?

Comment: Your argument doesn't quite make sense. You need to quantify $y$ and $x_0$, and the finite subcover from your collection could simply be the subcover containing $X$ itself.

Comment: @Neal I disagree. Of course, his proof isn't entirely written down, but he clearly explains the idea. But, instead of asking here if the idea is correct: How about you write down the proof with every single step and see yourself if it is correct? And if you are still not sure, you could ask it here?

Comment: There's something missing with the reasoning. Do you assume that $X$ is totally ordered to begin with? I'm not sure where "since we have a total order" comes from. Because otherwise your "rays" need not be a cover. In fact in a pathological case, only empty set can be a ray (e.g. when no two distinct points are comparable).

Comment: I have edited the post, hopefully so it is clear. I thought ordered topological space means exactly with a total order, with rays as its subase.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur ordered topological space can be defined for any poset. Anyway, the reasoning is still incorrect. Your $\mathcal{C}$ is not a cover. Consider an example: $X=[0,1]$ and note that $1$ doesn't belong to any ray.

Comment: But $[0,1]$ is bounded. Under the assumption towards contradiction that $X$ is unbounded, we obtain that it is a cover. Or atleast so I think.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur oh, yes, you're right. Well, it looks ok to me.

Comment: And actually this generalizes to any (non-totally) ordered space. Due to Zorn's lemma. And finally: yes, you can replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $X$ and the result still holds.

Comment: @freakish  Not so fast!  How you defining a topology for non-linear  ordered spaces?

Comment: @WilliamElliot the same. Generated by open intervals.

Comment: Multipoint compact antichains do not have a maximum.@freakish  R×R with the product order is discrete.  There is no commonly accepted topology for orders.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I'm confused, **every** point of any antichain is maximal (in the antichain), obviously. And how is $R\times R$ discrete under the topology I've talked about? It is not. Regardless, it is not compact. Again, Im not sure what your point is.

Comment: The open upper rays of (0,0) is  { (x,y) : 0 < x, 0 <= y or 0 <= x, 0 < y } .  Intersect that with the open lower ray of (1,0) to get  (0,1)×{0}. Like to get a horizontal line segment.  Intersect the two to get an open point.@freakish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A non-empty LOTS (linearly ordered topological space) $(X,<)$ is compact iff every subset $A \subseteq X$ has a supremum $\sup(A)$.

I show that in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1743735/4280), so I won't repeat that proof here;

This includes $\sup(\emptyset)=\min(X)$ and $\sup(X)=\max(X)$.

But the minor corollary has an easy enough proof, as you showed:

Let $X$ be compact, and suppose it has no maximum. Let $L(x)=\{y \in X: y < x\}$ for all $x \in X$, which are open sets by the definition of the order topology.

When $X$ has no maximum, these sets form an open cover of $X$ (if $x \in X$, there must be some $x' > x$, and then $x$ is covered by $L(x')$), so finitely many, say $\{L(x): x \in F\}$ are a finite subcover, for some finite $F \subseteq X$. But then $m=\max(F)$ (exists in any linearly ordered set as $F$ is finite) cannot be covered by them, contradiction: there is no finite subcover and this contradicts compactness. So $\max(X)$ must exist.

The argument for $\min(X)$ is almost the same, but using the other subbasic elememts $U(x)=\{y \in X: x > y\}$ as the open cover and $\min(F)$ for the contradiction.

Comment: I was actually looking for some stronger result, and what you quote is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Nitpicking: I would include the empty space among the LOTS, and it has no max.

Answer (score 2):

Let S be a compact linear ordered topological space (LOT).
If S is not empty, then S has a maximum element.
Proof,  Assume otherwise.
Thus for all x in S exists y in S with x < y.
D(a) = { x in S : x < a } is open.
Show { D(x) : x in S } covers S.
As S is compact, there is a finite subcover,
Show that is contradictory.

Likewise the order dual theorem compact LOTS have a minimum element.